# Error creating EntityManagerFactory while trying to connect to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make the ASP.NET MVCMusicStore using Spring.

Im using maven for dependencies, jetty as server and a MySQL database.

I get this error at run-time:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   [PersistenceUnit: MVCMusicStorePU] Unable to build
>   EntityManagerFactory

Can you help me, please. I would be very grateful.

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>musicstore</groupId>
<artifactId>MVCMusicStore</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>MVCMusicStore Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>java.net2</id>
        <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <url>http://ftp.ing.umu.se/mirror/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
        <id>eclipselink</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[eclipselink]</name>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>Jboss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>java.net.glassfish</id>
        <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>mesir-repo</id>
        <name>Repository hosting the oracle ojdbc14.jar</name>
        <url>http://mesir.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>junit</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>junit</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>3.8.1</version> -->
    <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <!-- Prepare for Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Prepare for Hibernate -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- prepare for database connection - Oracle - SQL - MySQL -->

    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>ojdbc</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>14</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>javax.sql</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>2.0</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- prepare for Spring framwork -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AOP dependence -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Prepare for Spring Rest -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Prepare for log system -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- This dependence is for Jsp configuration -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>MVCMusicStore</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-javaagent D:/spring-agent.jar</argLine>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-javaagent D:/spring-agent.jar</argLine>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">

<!-- Use @Component annotation for bean definitions -->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.MVCMusicStore" />

<!-- @Controller annotaitons for MVC controller definitions -->

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!--Add JPA support -->

<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MVCMusicStorePU" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
</bean>
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"
    lazy-init="true" />
<bean id="jpaAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"
    lazy-init="true" />

<!-- Add Transaction support -->
<bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>

<!-- Use @Transaction annotation for managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager"
    proxy-target-class="true" />

<!-- Declare a view resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolever"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    
        org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

```
    <!-- For MySQL -->

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springMusic" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Error log:

```
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

2012-04-18 21:30:11.877:INFO:/music:Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
2012-04-18 21:30:12.961:WARN:/music:unavailable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MVCMusicStorePU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)

Comment: For starters stop mixing hibernate versions. You are trying to mix 3.5 and 5.2 that is never going to happen. And you also have some old hibernate ejb3 dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I must remove code bellow?:
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>